# Can I have 2 mysql_fetch_array() inside a while loop? [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to display data from 2 different SQL Tables (normalised database) and display the data side by side in an HTML Table.

I can display the data from Table A and from Table B, however, I achieve this from two separate while-loops. I would like to combine these while-loops into one.

Question: can I have 2 mysql_fetch_array() conditions inside a while-loop?

Displaying data from Table A:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from ReportValues WHERE
ReportValues.ReportID = '$Report_Values'");
while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $myData[2] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Displaying data from Table B:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Element WHERE Element.ElementsID
= (SELECT ElementsID FROM Template WHERE Template.TID = '$Temp')");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Ideally I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from ReportValues 
                       WHERE ReportValues.ReportID = '$Report_Values'");

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Element 
                        WHERE Element.ElementsID = 
                          (SELECT ElementsID FROM Template 
                           WHERE Template.TID = '$Temp'
                          )"
                       );

while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) && 
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $myData[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
Thank you for all the replies, however, I couldn't manage to implement what was suggested. My work around included creating arrays, and for each element (data[$i] and row[$i]) I just added them into 2 separate arrays. I still used two separate while-loops. Probably inefficient/poor code, but I got it working, ha.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know, did it work for you?

Comment: You can yes, but if there are a different number of rows returned in each query then the loop will stop when there are no more results in the one with fewer rows.

Comment: It is strongly advised you switch from `mysql_` functions to drivers such as MySQLi or PDO, as `mysql_` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and completely removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: Seems like you could use `||` instead of `&&` to prevent what @AbraCadaver referred to. You would then have to check that `$myData` and `$row` were set before printing.

Comment: With my ideal code, it only displays $row[] values and completely misses out the first half of the condition (ie $myData[])

Comment: If you wanna manualy parse the 2nd resource, you can use an `$i` var and http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Comment: Nah, got it working with a poor work around. Check edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can yes, but if there are a different number of rows returned in each query then the loop will stop when there are no more results in the one with fewer rows:

```
while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) &&
       $row    = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $myData[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

To keep looping for the query with the most rows you could use an `OR`, but you need to check if the variable is set:

```
while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) ||
       $row    = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . isset($myData[2]) ? $myData[2] : '' . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . isset($row[2]) ? $myData[2] : ''  . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```